# "Connection was reset" error on flask server

Tags: python, docker, flask

I'm having an issue with dockers, I followed official docker tutorial to deploy a web app (and luckily a python/flask one) but when I tried to deploy my app when I come to the connection part it failed and reply "Connection was reset"

**Code**

---

```py
    import json
    import threading
    import thread
    import io

    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO

    # Global variables
    app = Flask(__name__)

    lock = threading.Semaphore(0)
    IOCReplay.lock = lock

    async_mode = None
    socketio = SocketIO(app)
    IOCReplay.socketio = socketio


    @app.route("/")
    def root():
        return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route("/dependencies")
    def getDependencies():
        data = ''
        with open('./dependencies.json') as data_file:
            data = json.load(data_file)

        return json.dumps(data)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        socketio.run(app, port=5000)
```

```sh
    docker run -d -P guitest:1
    6d95689601b8(...)

    docker ps
    CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              
    6d95689601b8        guitest:1           "python test.py"   

    CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                       NAMES
    4 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        0.0.0.0:32771->5000/tcp     loving_boyd
```

Dockerfile is OK.

### Issue

And so when I'm logging into 0.0.0.0:32771 it says "Connection was reset"

I saw from docker FAQ that to correct this problem, i have to "change the service’s configuration on [my] localhost so that the service accepts requests from all IPs"

Comment: I am no Mac user, but some students of us had a similar problem with OS X, because they used docker-machine to run an application. Therefore, they had to use the docker-machine's ip address to access the application and not "localhost" as it is usual on Linux machines or if you installed the native docker client.

Comment: Thank you n2o for your reply!
So you think I should run a docker-machine instead of the regular docker thing so that I can link my web app to an IP adress so I will avoid all the localhost possible conflict between the VM and the host?

Comment: Nope, the docker-machine solution is pretty old and was a workaround. Using the native docker client should be the way to go ("Docker for Mac" I think). I do not know what you have installed, this was only a suggestion where your problem might result from.

Comment: Do you have any output in your flask container? What are the errors? You can use `docker logs <container-id>` or you connect to your container and look for the log files.

Comment: I updated the thread so it will be more useful to show you, but the problem (or part of it) was from uncomplete or wrong parameters of the socketio.run(app, port) so i added socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port)

BUT I also removed all the weird imports that python uses like threading, json.

I will try to add the others functions step by step, and thank you for the docker logs and some info about docker-machine which is supposed to be the next step for me :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I have solved all my problems! Thanks to @n2o

The problem was incorrect arguments for socketio.run(app)

Previous:

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO

    # Code here #

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        socketio.run(app, port=5000)
```

Fixed:

```py
    import os
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request
    from flask_socketio import SocketIO

    # code here #

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000))
        socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=port)
```

Comment: Please mark your own answer as correct, you do not need to add this to your title ;-)

Comment: Ok but it says that I have to wait 24hours more :-(

Comment: Ah okay, did not think about it ;-)